# Nhibernate and Query example

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, nhibernate, hql

```
class Customer
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class Order
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Product { get; set; }
}

var customers = new Customer[]
{
    new Customer{ID = 5, Name = "Sam"},
    new Customer{ID = 6, Name = "Dave"},
    new Customer{ID = 7, Name = "Julia"},
    new Customer{ID = 8, Name = "Sue"}
};

var orders = new Order[]
{
    new Order{ID = 5, Product = "Book"},
    new Order{ID = 6, Product = "Game"},
    new Order{ID = 7, Product = "Computer"},
    new Order{ID = 8, Product = "Shirt"}
};

IEnumerable<Object> query = 
    from c in customers
    join o in orders on c.ID equals o.ID
    select new { c.Name, o.Product };
IList<Object> AA = query.ToList<Object>();
```

This one return new object that is shown into picture 
   [But I want to access this object as customer and order  how can I get data as 'customerObject.propertyName and   order.propertyName" instead of getting array with string.  Can I get list of data with two object like customer and  order object so I can access those data using that object]
It `returns aa[0] = {name=" sam ", product=" Book"}` but I want something like `aa[0] = {Customer.Name , Order.product }` 
[1]

Comment: It returns aa[0] = {name=" sam ", product=" Book"}
but I want something like  aa[0] = {Customer.Name , Order.product }

Comment: You can edit the original question. Please put additional information there, and not in a comment.

Comment: Your question is hard to read, please rewrite it. Otherwise it will probably never be useful to anyone else, missing the purpose of stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to return the mapped objects. Considering you have your mapped entities, try something like this:

```
var result = (from c in customers
             join o in orders on c.ID equals o.ID
             select new{ Customer = c, Product = o.Product })
             .ToList();
```

Then you can access you `result` object as a collection of anonymous objects where you have the `Customer` property and `Product` which has your entities.

Comment: Thank you so much it is working perfect one things only i want to change is that o.product remove that and write down o only